# how to get catalog products filtering attribute code magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9

Actually i want to get catalog products filtering attribute code magento 1.9.If anyone has idea regarding it.

generally we use Mage::getModel('catalog/product') here using this factory instance i want to filter the products with attribute codes

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Shop_Custommodule>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Shop_Custommodule>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <shop>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>Shop_Custommodule</module>
            <frontName>shop</frontName>
          </args>
      </shop>
    </routers>
        <layout>
          <updates>
            <shop>
              <file>shop.xml</file>
            </shop>
          </updates>
        </layout>
  </frontend>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <shop>
        <class>Shop_Custommodule_Helper</class>
      </shop>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <shop>
        <class>Shop_Custommodule_Block</class>
      </shop>
    </blocks>


  </global>
  <adminhtml>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <shop>
                                        <title>shop - All</title>
                                    </shop>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
  </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Comment: Unclear question. Please explain more.

Comment: generally we use Mage::getModel('catalog/product') here using this factory instance i want to filter the products with attribute codes